# how to incorporate parallel python with django

Tags: python, django, parallel-python

I was wondering if there is a way to incorporate pp (Parallel Python) with django. This would be great because I have multiple computers and I want to use them to better handle the requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

paralel python is for litle bit different tasks, and for this purposes it is better to use nginx as loadbalancer.